# Display File with HTML Markings in ListView

Tags: java, android, html, string, listview

I have an online .txt file I am downloading to my Downloads folder at `/mnt/sdcard/Download/testfile.txt` and then displaying it in a ListView. The .txt file contains html markings like `<html><head><title>` etc. that I wish to remove. I also need to replace all the `<br />` with `\n` in order for my `BufferedReader` to view them as new lines and add separate entries into the ListView.

Currently, it will load the text into a single ListView entry with all of the markup, not creating a new line at the `<br />`.

Below is my current code.

```
public void load() {
    try {
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                sdcard + "/Download/testfile.txt"));
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            if (line != "")
                entries.add(line);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, entries);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        bufferedReader.close();
    } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {       
    }
}
```

`testfile.txt` is as follows:
`<html><head><title>mytextfile</title></head><body style ='font-family:monospace:'>1. Line 1 - Item 1<br />2. Line 2 - Item 2<br />3. Line 3 - Item 3<br />4. Line 4 - Item 4<br />5. Line 5 - Item 5<br />6. Line 6 - Item 6<br />7. Line 7 - Item 7<br />8. Line 8 - Item 8<br />9. Line 9 - Item 9<br />10. Line 10 - Item 10<br />11. Line 11 - Item 11<br />12. Line 12 - Item 12<br />13. Line 13 - Item 13<br />14. Line 14 - Item 14<br />15. Line 15 - Item 15<br />16. Line 16 - Item 16<br />17. Line 17 - Item 17<br />18. Line 18 - Item 18<br />19. Line 19 - Item 19<br />20. Line 20 - Item 20</body></html>`

Comment: Could you share testfile.txt also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Java HTML parser to strip the html: http://jsoup.org/

`Jsoup.parse(yourHtmlString).text()` should do it.

Regarding your line-breaks, replace them:

`replaceAll("(<br />)", "\\\\n")`

What I cannot tell you  though is if there will be compatibility issues using that library with Android.

Comment: I get a NullPointerException error at `line.replaceAll("<br />", "\n");`

Comment: @Adam Sorry I fixed the replaceAll, look at the edit. NullPointerException tells me though that your 'line' is null, you might want to check that first.

Comment: By placing a `if (line != null)` statement before the replaceAll, there is no error, but changing it to `if (line == null)` forces an error, due to the BufferedReader not actually loading the file. As to why, I'm clueless.

Comment: That seems to be a different problem with reading your file. You can temporarily put your html-content in a string and test if the parsing and replacing of the line break works for you.

Comment: The call for the replaceAll(String, String) never seems to be called. I'm getting one single ListView entry with everything, the <br /> are still there.

Comment: Do you do something like `line = line.replaceAll("(<br />)", "\\\\n")`? Just passing it with replaceAll should suffice though. If your problem lies somewhere else you have to debug and look at it step by step, it's hard to guess. The replacing works though, I tested it.